# How can I only allow request from my form

Tags: php, forms, security, cross-domain

I have a form on a server and the php to process it, on an other server, this configuration cannot be changed.
I receive a lot of SPAM, and tried to fix it. SESSION couldn't works due to cross-domain, so no token and no captcha, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is not reliable. I'm thinking to implement an encrypted key which change once a day, but i think it's limited. Any better idea?

exemple of encrypted key:

```
$key = "string".date("d");
```

Comment: Are you getting a lot of spams from bots, or people from those sweat shops?

Comment: if sweat shops are sex shop, I receive both

Comment: Do you have control over both servers?

Comment: Yep. btw couldn't try the solutions now, i'll give a try monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of bots doesn't run javascript, so you could just inject an arbitrary field into your form:

```
<form id="douchebag" action="http://yourotherserver.com/process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
.. bunch of other inputs
</form>
```

Then your js:

```
var bugSpray = document.createElement('input');
bugSpray.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
bugSpray.setAttribute('name', 'aa');
bugSpray.value = 'bb';
document.getElementById('douchebag').appendChild(bugSpray);
```

then in your `process.php`

```
if(empty($_POST['aa']) || $_POST['aa'] != 'bb') // bot
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a session to use CAPTCHA.
Many kinds of CAPTCHA exist.
Even the following will probably keep 99% of spambots out:

```
<form action="...">
<input type="hidden" name="thequestion1" value="23">
<input type="hidden" name="thequestion2" value="-">
<input type="hidden" name="thequestion3" value="5">
How much is 23-5?
<input type="text" name="theanswer">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Most spambots don't look any futher than input fields and submitbuttons.

I bet this kind of CAPTCHA will keep most spam out.

PS: Be sure to safely evaluate the values of thequestion1, thequestion2, thequestion3 on the server.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've used before is similar to what @SiGanteng suggested but rather than adding a new field you can change the name attributes on exiting ones, to either remove or add a prefix.

```
<script>
var inputs = document.getElementById('myform').getElementsByTagname('input');
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].name = "antispam_" + inputs[i].name;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for example add a new resource on the server which generates a key and stores it in a database. When the web page is loaded you request a new key from the server and insert it into a `hidden` form field.

Then, when a request has been made, you check the value of this field and see that there is a corresponding key in your database. If not, discard the request.

Of course, it is still possible for bots to circumvent it (by also requesting a key), but it will be harder.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is using a simple check, 
take two text inputs and concatenate them, 
make an md5 of them and send this through POST.
On the other server check this and Voila.